# How to summon a FallingSand entity preventing it from becoming solid?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[This video from SimplySarc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36rIqGnXrcE) shows how to do that, but it doesn't work anymore in 1.9. In 1.9, it simply summons a item frame with a FallingSand entity on top. After a few seconds, the ItemFrame disappears and the FallingSand falls on the ground where it becomes solid.

**Is there a way to prevent a specific FallingSand entity from becoming solid using the /summon command like in the video from SimplySarc?**

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you summon a FallingSand which rides on top of another entity.
 The problem is, the sand is then floating on top of the entity, so it is not on ground directly.

If you use an ArmorStand, the offset is very high and it can not be affected by TNT / Creepers.

If you use an item, which is uncollectable, it works quite good:

> `/summon Item ~ ~10 ~ {Item:{id:sand,Count:1},Health:2147483647,PickupDelay:32767,Passengers:[{id:"FallingSand",Block:0,Data:0,Time:1,DropItem:0}]}`

[image]

When nearby explosions it will be affected, but as soon as it lands it will become solid.

Hope it helped :)